# Como puedo obtener la salida de un script en docker desde un script en php?

Tags: php, bash, docker

Tengo un script en php que ejecuta una imagen de docker y espera su salida para seguir, pero no esta implementado de forma asíncrona; por tanto tengo que esperar un tiempo para chequear si tengo salida o un error. Aquí va el código.

```
$action = "timeout 5m bash script.sh";

exec($action,$result);
        $output = array(
                'publi_err'         => 1,
                'yt_start_error'    => 1,
                'yt_end_error'      => 1,
            );
```

El problema es que me da el siguiente error antes del tiempo de espera:

```
write /dev/stdout: The pipe is being closed.
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: El contenedor de docker por su cuenta sin php funciona bien?

Comment: Sip, funciona perfectamente... solo que cuando la salida es muy grande arroja ese error

Comment: Bueno, al menos ya sabes que tu problema no tiene que ver con php. Si con docker sin php también te ocurre... ¿Y se puede saber algo sobre el contenedor? ¿qué hace? ¿el comando docker run para invocarlo o el Dockerfile? es que si no, es difícil ayudar.